# android PostResponseAsyncTask some times error when url is online and no if in local server

Tags: android

I try upload image to local server and it successfully, but when I try upload to my database online some times there have error in code `task.execute(FIXURL+"upload_WC.php");`

this my code..

```
public void Upload(){
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(selectedPhoto).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
            String encodedImage = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
            Log.d(TAG, encodedImage);

            HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            postData.put("image", encodedImage);
            postData.put("Latitude2", Latitude);
            postData.put("Longitude2", Longitude);

            PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(WC_Activity.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    if(s.contains("uploaded_success")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while uploading.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            task.execute(FIXURL+"upload_WC.php");

            task.setEachExceptionsHandler(new EachExceptionsHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleIOException(IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Connect to Server.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void handleMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL Error.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void handleProtocolException(ProtocolException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Protocol Error.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void handleUnsupportedEncodingException(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encoding Error.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Something Wrong while encoding photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and this is the logcat

```
07-16 18:55:48.228 26223-26223/com.emergency.e_place E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.emergency.e_place, PID: 26223
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:576)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                                                                           at com.emergency.e_place.WC_Activity.Upload(WC_Activity.java:153)
                                                                           at com.emergency.e_place.WC_Activity$6.onClick(WC_Activity.java:196)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:153)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask can only be executed once. Are you calling execute somewhere else in your code?

you can use AsyncTask more than once by new CLASS_NAME().execute() CLASS_NAME extends AsyncTask, without create instance from CLASS_NAME